Перевод djoser email confiramations
Вопрос не требует кода.
Написал модуль авторизации на django + djoser + simple JWT.
Сначала стал предопределять emal класс и template. Но потом обратил внимание, что, например, письмо подтверждения регистрации приходит полностью на английском. А письмо со ссылкой на сброс пароля - почти полностью на русском.
Не могу понять, почему перевод происходит так выборочно. Очевидно, не все шаблоны перевода есть или подтянулись. Подскажите, кто сталкивался, как их дополнить или обновить, чтобы избежать ненужного кода в виде переопределения.
Пытался собрать свою локаль в папку, но ругается на версию GNU, что мол должна быть больше 0.15 хотя у меня стоит 0.21.
Сейчас все откатил, и из языковых настроек осталась только LANGUAGE_CODE = 'ru'
Кстати, как правильно указывать: 'ru-ru', 'ru-Ru', 'ru-RU' или просто 'ru'? Если подскажите ссылкой на документацию, буду благодарен. Потому что в сети все варианты встречаются, а как верно не понятно. При этом, обратил внимание, что в local самого пакета django есть только каталог 'ru'
